# How to manage state through Context and typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-context

So I'm trying to learn how to use context since I'm building a dating app for dogs just as a fun project and will have to pass the current user throughout the whole application.

Tho i don't seem to grasp how to use context with typescript. I have a component called HomeView and would like to view counter and possibly set the counter with the usestate function setCounter.

When I try to log the counter in my HomeView components all I get is undefined even tho the value is set to 0. I should be able to log 0 onto the screen in my consumer. What am I missing?

**Contex.tsx**

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

type ContextType = {
  setCounter: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
  counter: number;
};

export const CounterContext = createContext<ContextType>({} as ContextType);

export const CounterContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return <CounterContext.Provider value={{ counter, setCounter }}>{children}</CounterContext.Provider>;
};
```

**HomeView.tsx**

```
export const HomeView = () => {
  const context = useContext(CounterContext);
  console.log(context.counter); // value is undefined

  return (
    <div className='signInWrapper'>
      <SignIn />
      <CounterContextProvider>
        {context.counter}  // Nothing is shown onto the screen
      </CounterContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `HomeView` needs to be a child of `CounterContextProvider`. Also, this has nothing to do with Typescript which is just a bad version of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are retrieving the context in a component which is not nested in the `CounterContext.Provider` itself you are getting `undefined`.

You should nest your entire application in the `CounterContextProvider` in order to access the state globally.
You can do this in your `App.js` file:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <CounterContextProvider>
        ...
        <HomeView/>
    </CounterContextProvider>
```

After this you should be able to access the context in your `HomeView` component:

```
export const HomeView = () => {
  const { counter, setCounter } = useContext(CounterContext);

  return (
    <div className='signInWrapper'>
      <SignIn />
      Your counter value is: {counter}
    </div>
  );
};
```